# How to do I save a highscore for simple 2D game similar to flappy bird in android studio project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, save

I am new to programming and so I'm not sure where my code is failing. I have tried to add a save feature for people's high-scores and have tried searching for the answers myself before asking for help. I understand that shared preferences are needed and I have added the code and there's no errors however it doesn't actually save the high-score so the code I have added is pretty redundant right now. Please can someone point me in the right direction? I have added my code below.

EDIT- I have checked my code and under shared preferences I have put int score (this is what i was going to code as the basic score at first but then I changed it to player.getScore later. Anyway when I try to amend score to player.getScore it cannot resolve player.getScore, how do i fix it and once that's been done will my game save the high score?

Thanks for any help.

```
package com.curtis.myfirstgame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
public static final int WIDTH = 856;
public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
public static final int MOVESPEED = -5;
private long smokeStartTime;
private long missileStartTime;
private MainThread thread;
private Background bg;
private Player player;
private ArrayList<Smokepuff> smoke;
private ArrayList<Missile> missiles;
private ArrayList<TopBorder> topborder;
private ArrayList<BotBorder> botborder;
private Random rand = new Random();
private int maxBorderHeight;
private int minBorderHeight;
private boolean topDown = true;
private boolean botDown = true;
private boolean newGameCreated;
public static int Score = 0;
public static int HighScore = 0;

public static SharedPreferences prefs;

private String saveScore = "HighScore";

//increase to slow down difficulty progression, decrease to speed up      difficulty progression
private int progressDenom = 20;

private Explosion explosion;
private long startReset;
private boolean reset;
private boolean dissapear;
private boolean started;


public GamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);


    SharedPreferences prefs =   context.getSharedPreferences("com.curtis.myfirstgame", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int player.getScore = prefs.getInt("highScore", 0); 
         //above is where my problem is


    String spackage = "com.curtis.myfirstgame";

    HighScore = prefs.getInt(saveScore, 0);

    //add the callback to the surfaceholder to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    //make gamePanel focusable so it can handle events
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    int counter = 0;
    while (retry && counter < 1000) {
        counter++;
        try {
            thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
            thread = null;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            prefs.edit().putInt(saveScore, HighScore).commit();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    bg = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  R.drawable.grassbg1));
    player = new Player(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.helicopter), 65, 25, 3);
    smoke = new ArrayList<Smokepuff>();
    missiles = new ArrayList<Missile>();
    topborder = new ArrayList<TopBorder>();
    botborder = new ArrayList<BotBorder>();
    smokeStartTime = System.nanoTime();
    missileStartTime = System.nanoTime();

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    //we can safely start the game loop
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (!player.getPlaying() && newGameCreated && reset) {
            player.setPlaying(true);
            player.setUp(true);
        }
        if (player.getPlaying()) {

            if (!started) started = true;
            reset = false;
            player.setUp(true);
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        player.setUp(false);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void update() {
    if (player.getPlaying()) {

        if (botborder.isEmpty()) {
            player.setPlaying(false);
            return;
        }
        if (topborder.isEmpty()) {
            player.setPlaying(false);
            return;
        }

        bg.update();
        player.update();

        //calculate the threshold of height the border can have based on the score
        //max and min border heart are updated, and the border switched direction when either max or
        //min is met

        maxBorderHeight = 30 + player.getScore() / progressDenom;
        //cap max border height so that borders can only take up a total of 1/2 the screen
        if (maxBorderHeight > HEIGHT / 4) maxBorderHeight = HEIGHT / 4;
        minBorderHeight = 5 + player.getScore() / progressDenom;

        //check bottom border collision
        for (int i = 0; i < botborder.size(); i++) {
            if (collision(botborder.get(i), player))
                player.setPlaying(false);
        }

        //check top border collision
        for (int i = 0; i < topborder.size(); i++) {
            if (collision(topborder.get(i), player))
                player.setPlaying(false);
        }

        //update top border
        this.updateTopBorder();

        //udpate bottom border
        this.updateBottomBorder();

        //add missiles on timer
        long missileElapsed = (System.nanoTime() - missileStartTime) / 1000000;
        if (missileElapsed > (2000 - player.getScore() / 4)) {
            //first missile always goes down the middle
            if (missiles.size() == 0) {
                missiles.add(new Missile(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.
                        missile), WIDTH + 10, HEIGHT / 2, 45, 15, player.getScore(), 13));
            }
            else {

                missiles.add(new Missile(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.missile),
                        WIDTH + 10, (int) (rand.nextDouble() * (HEIGHT - (maxBorderHeight * 2)) + maxBorderHeight), 45, 15, player.getScore(), 13));
            }

            //reset timer
            missileStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
        //loop through every missile and check collision and remove
        for (int i = 0; i < missiles.size(); i++) {
            //update missile
            missiles.get(i).update();

            if (collision(missiles.get(i), player)) {
                missiles.remove(i);
                player.setPlaying(false);
                break;
            }
            //remove missile if it is way off the screen
            if (missiles.get(i).getX() < -100) {
                missiles.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        //add smoke puffs on timer
        long elapsed = (System.nanoTime() - smokeStartTime) / 1000000;
        if (elapsed > 120) {
            smoke.add(new Smokepuff(player.getX(), player.getY() + 10));
            smokeStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < smoke.size(); i++) {
            smoke.get(i).update();
            if (smoke.get(i).getX() < -10) {
                smoke.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        player.resetDY();
        if (!reset) {
            newGameCreated = false;
            startReset = System.nanoTime();
            reset = true;
            dissapear = true;
            explosion = new Explosion(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.explosion), player.getX(),
                    player.getY() - 30, 100, 100, 25);
        }

        explosion.update();
        long resetElapsed = (System.nanoTime() - startReset) / 1000000;

        if (resetElapsed > 2500 && !newGameCreated) {
            newGame();
        }
    }
}

public boolean collision(GameObject a, GameObject b) {
    if (Rect.intersects(a.getRectangle(), b.getRectangle())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    final float scaleFactorX = getWidth() / (WIDTH * 1.f);
    final float scaleFactorY = getHeight() / (HEIGHT * 1.f);

    if (canvas != null) {
        final int savedState = canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
        bg.draw(canvas);
        if (!dissapear) {
            player.draw(canvas);
        }
        //draw smokepuffs
        for (Smokepuff sp : smoke) {
            sp.draw(canvas);
        }
        //draw missiles
        for (Missile m : missiles) {
            m.draw(canvas);
        }

        //draw topborder
        for (TopBorder tb : topborder) {
            tb.draw(canvas);
        }

        //draw botborder
        for (BotBorder bb : botborder) {
            bb.draw(canvas);
        }
        //draw explosion
        if (started) {
            explosion.draw(canvas);
        }
        drawText(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
    }
}

public void updateTopBorder() {
    //every 50 points, insert randomly placed top blocks that break the pattern
    if (player.getScore() % 50 == 0) {
        topborder.add(new TopBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick
        ), topborder.get(topborder.size() - 1).getX() + 20, 0, (int) ((rand.nextDouble() * (maxBorderHeight
        )) + 1)));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < topborder.size(); i++) {
        topborder.get(i).update();
        if (topborder.get(i).getX() < -20) {
            topborder.remove(i);
            //remove element of arraylist, replace it by adding a new one

            //calculate topdown which determines the direction the border is moving (up or down)
            if (topborder.get(topborder.size() - 1).getHeight() >= maxBorderHeight) {
                topDown = false;
            }
            if (topborder.get(topborder.size() - 1).getHeight() <= minBorderHeight) {
                topDown = true;
            }
            //new border added will have larger height
            if (topDown) {
                topborder.add(new TopBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.brick), topborder.get(topborder.size() - 1).getX() + 20,
                        0, topborder.get(topborder.size() - 1).getHeight() + 1));
            }
            //new border added wil have smaller height
            else {
                topborder.add(new TopBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.brick), topborder.get(topborder.size() - 1).getX() + 20,
                        0, topborder.get(topborder.size() - 1).getHeight() - 1));
            }
        }
    }
}

public void updateBottomBorder() {
    //every 40 points, insert randomly placed bottom blocks that break pattern
    if (player.getScore() % 40 == 0) {
        botborder.add(new BotBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick),
                botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1).getX() + 20, (int) ((rand.nextDouble()
                * maxBorderHeight) + (HEIGHT - maxBorderHeight))));
    }

    //update bottom border
    for (int i = 0; i < botborder.size(); i++) {
        botborder.get(i).update();

        //if border is moving off screen, remove it and add a corresponding new one
        if (botborder.get(i).getX() < -20) {
            botborder.remove(i);

            //determine if border will be moving up or down
            if (botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1).getY() <= HEIGHT - maxBorderHeight) {
                botDown = true;
            }
            if (botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1).getY() >= HEIGHT - minBorderHeight) {
                botDown = false;
            }

            if (botDown) {
                botborder.add(new BotBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick
                ), botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1).getX() + 20, botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1
                ).getY() + 1));
            }
            else {
                botborder.add(new BotBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick
                ), botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1).getX() + 20, botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1
                ).getY() - 1));
            }
        }
    }
}

public void newGame() {
    dissapear = false;

    botborder.clear();
    topborder.clear();

    missiles.clear();
    smoke.clear();

    minBorderHeight = 5;
    maxBorderHeight = 30;

    player.resetDY();
    player.resetScore();
    player.setY(HEIGHT / 2);

    //update score only if new score is higher


    if (player.getScore() > HighScore) {
        HighScore = player.getScore();
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putInt("highScore", HighScore);
        edit.commit();
    }

    //create initial borders

    //initial top border
    for (int i = 0; i * 20 < WIDTH + 40; i++) {
        //first top border create
        if (i == 0) {
            topborder.add(new TopBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick
            ), i * 20, 0, 10));
        }
        else {
            topborder.add(new TopBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick
            ), i * 20, 0, topborder.get(i - 1).getHeight() + 1));
        }
    }
    //initial bottom border
    for (int i = 0; i * 20 < WIDTH + 40; i++) {
        //first border ever created
        if (i == 0) {
            botborder.add(new BotBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick)
                    , i * 20, HEIGHT - minBorderHeight));
        }
        //adding borders until the initial screen is filed
        else {
            botborder.add(new BotBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick),
                    i * 20, botborder.get(i - 1).getY() - 1));
        }
    }
    newGameCreated = true;
}


public void drawText(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(30);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
    canvas.drawText("SCORE: " + (player.getScore() * 3), 10, HEIGHT - 10, paint);
    canvas.drawText("HIGHSCORE: " + HighScore, WIDTH - 215, HEIGHT - 10, paint);

    if (!player.getPlaying() && newGameCreated && reset) {
        Paint paint1 = new Paint();
        paint1.setTextSize(40);
        paint1.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
        canvas.drawText("PRESS TO START", WIDTH / 2 - 50, HEIGHT / 2, paint1);

        paint1.setTextSize(20);
        canvas.drawText("PRESS AND HOLD TO GO UP", WIDTH / 2 - 50, HEIGHT / 2 + 20, paint1);
        canvas.drawText("RELEASE TO GO DOWN", WIDTH / 2 - 50, HEIGHT / 2 + 40, paint1);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Get the highscore from prefs, if it's smaller than the current score, then save current score as highscore.

Comment: `Database` or a `sharedPreference`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Do following

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int oldScore = prefs.getInt("highScore", 0);  
//update score only if new score is higher
    if(newScore > oldScore ){
       Editor edit = prefs.edit();
       edit.putInt("highScore", newScore);
       edit.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
SharedPreferences preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();

Integer score = preference.getInt("score",null);               //read from pref
if(classFound == null) 
{  editor.putInt("score",100);              //write to pref
   editor.commit();                                           
}
```

Use **Integer** as int is not nullabe.

You can save any int value by replacing 100 with a variable

Give an upvote if it helped :)